# Error al conectarme a postgres con python dentro de un contenedor

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, virtualbox

Estoy usando una maquina virtual (virtual box) y dentro tengo docker con contenedores de postgres y python, con dbeaver me puedo conectar correctamente a postgres pero cuando estoy dentro del contenedor de python no puedo conectarme a postgres por me da este error

DBeaver conectado correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
OperationalError('could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n')
```

de esta manera trato de realizar la conexión:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    cnx = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', dbname='db_prueba', user='usuario', password='contrasenia')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

comando para postgres:

```
docker run 
--name db_postgres 
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=contrasenia
-e POSTGRES_USER=usuario
-p 5432:5432
--restart always
-d postgres
```

aquí están las reglas de puertos que tengo configuradas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en que yo al querer conectarme estaba apuntando al contenedor de Python y yo tenia que apuntar hacia la maquina

mal

```
cnx = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', dbname='db_prueba', user='usuario', password='contrasenia')
```

Bien

```
cnx = psycopg2.connect(host='10.0.2.201', dbname='db_prueba', user='usuario', password='contrasenia')
```

Answer (score 0):

en teoria te falta   --network="host"   en el run del docker.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

(OPCIONAL) Y tambien cambiaria el handling te dara problemas (te paso un ejemplo)

```
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(user=postgress_username,
                  password=postgress_password,
                  host=postgress_password,
                  port='5432',
                  database=postgress_database)

    cur = con.cursor()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print('Error while connecting to PostgreSQL', error)
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda un saludo